# Cannot connect to remote Linux server from my router, but can via direct connection to the modem

Tags: router, ssh, putty

So our school has Linux servers and we use them from home to submit our assignments and etc. I always use PuTTy to connect to the server and I never had any problems. However since last week I get an error trying to connect to the server. I get this error:

> Network Error: Software caused connection abort.

At first I thought the problem is my laptop, so I used my phone (using the ConnectBot program) to connect to the servers and I wasn’t able to. So I disconnected my phone from home Wi-Fi and connected it to my LTE, and then I was able to connect to the servers.

I figured either my router or my ISP is blocking me. So I connected my laptop to the ISP modem through LAN (I have a modem which is provided by my ISP and a wireless router) and I was able to connect to the servers.

So I figured the problem is my wireless router, however I haven’t changed any settings or anything and couldn’t find anything online so I didn't know what caused this issue.

I factory reset my router and tried again, and I still had the same issue. It is driving me crazy. I don't know what to do anymore and can’t find anything online.

Comment: Is the school network administrator able to offer any insight or suggestions?

Comment: Yes Im using windows, I get a response from the server. I even used nmap and checked the port 22 and it says it is open. I did the traceroute as well and there was no issue. I used the direct ip and got the same error.